# How to open Filtered VIM file without overwriting current text

Tags: vim, grep, neovim

I have a file in VIM with a bunch of names on separate lines.

I want to open this file with filtered results (easier to view).
BUT, I want to preserve the other lines/names.

Example:

```
#open names file only show names that begin with a
vim names.txt | grep “a.*”
```

**I know the above won’t work** but *hypothetically* speaking if it were to open with the desired functionality (displaying only names starting with a) and I then made changes to those name, and finally saved the file.

I would like to open the file normally without grep and see the rest of the names unaffected.

**What I tried…**

```
 cat names.txt | grep “a.*” > names.txt
```

Unfortunately this does not work because it will overwrite the current names.txt file once i run *:wq* in vim.

Any and all help / suggestions are appreciated

**Clarifying the use case**
The intention is to take each name in a file filter it with a specific pattern. Make changes to those matches and then save the file.
So I want to edit all the names that match “^ab”. I’ll make a change to the name. The reason for filtering is for visuals but also to more easily apply macros. Also some tasks are easier since VIM does not support non-continuous highlighting.

The file will have changes - those names that matched the pattern for the filter. But, I want those names that were not matches to remain original.

Comment: The closest I have been able to get is using the filter feature built into VIM. Using “:g/^a” Will show all the names that begin with a only but i can not perform actions with this filtered list as when I press any key the filter is removed.

Comment: Do you need to make changes to `names.txt` (preserving the original order) or is this just for your reading convenience? BTW, it's `grep <pattern> <file(s)>`. No need to `cat` stuff in. Finally, `a.*` will match *a lot*, probably more than intended.

Comment: You should replace your fancy curly quotes with straight ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual use case is not super clear.

### Do you want to edit the filtered lines without affecting the original file?

#### From within Vim

If the file is already loaded in Vim, you can do `:g/foo` to list the lines matching your pattern at the bottom of the screen until you press a key.

Another method consists in putting the content of the file in a new buffer and then filtering it:

```
:vnew | r# | v/foo/d
```

which should leave you with two windows, one with the original file and one with the filtered lines.

#### From your shell

If your shell supports [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), you can do:

```
$ vim <(grep foo filename)
```

where the output of `grep foo filename` is presented to Vim as a "file".

### Do you want to navigate between the matching lines without affecting the original content?

#### From within Vim

Simply use `:help :vimgrep` and `:help quickfix`:

```
:vimgrep foo | cwindow
```

#### From your shell

You can tell Vim to use the content of a "file" to build a quickfix list with the `-q` flag and execute an arbitrary command afterward with the `+` flag:

```
$ vim -q <(grep -nH foo filename) +cwindow
```

See `:help -q` and `:help -+c`.

Comment: Didn't know about `vim -q` ... it is pretty cool.

Comment: Indeed it is cool.

Comment: This is probably the closest to achieving the functionality I need. In the split screen is it possible to merge the changes to the original document. This would basically achieve what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Your clarified use case sounds like :help :cdo.

Comment: Using this with some manual copy and pasting i was able to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Run `grep '^a' <file_path> | vim -` in the command line to load the filtered names into a temporary buffer, and the original file won't be affected.

Option 2: If the line order does not matter to you, try `:g/^a/ m0` in vim to move the target names to the top of the file. That might be easier to view.

Comment: Option 3: `:sort`

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic addendum to the existing answers: you can use the `hlsearch` option to highlight the last search result.

The following two lines won't hide everything else but highlight lines beginning with an 'a', making them easier to spot:

```
:set hlsearch
/^a.*
```

Having `hlsearch` set is always nice to have. You can temporarily disable highlighting using the `:nohlsearch` command.